# change a datafield in WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, sharepoint-2013

I have a developed page and web part like this

```
<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" IsIncluded="True" AsyncRefresh="false" FrameType="None" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" ViewFlag="8" 
                        Title="Users List" PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW" __markuptype="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{70C58E07-EDC8-4E42-9FAF-C3CCB516466B}" 
                        id="g_70c58e07_edc8_4e42_9faf_c3ccb516466b" listname="{E855D4F1-5106-48FE-AC42-AE5992837C20}" pagesize="1" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" 
                        WebPart="true" Height="" Width="">
<DataSources>
    <SharePointWebControls:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true" UseServerDataFormat="true" selectcommand="&lt;
                        View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;And&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ID&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;
                        Counter&quot;&gt;{paramCategory}&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Active&quot;/&gt;&lt;
                        Value Type=&quot;Boolean&quot;&gt;1&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/And&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" id="dataformwebpart3">
        <SelectParameters>
            <WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{E855D4F1-5106-48FE-AC42-AE5992837C20}"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="StartRowIndex" DefaultValue="0"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="nextpagedata" DefaultValue="0"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="MaximumRows" DefaultValue="1"/>
            <WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="paramCategory" ParameterKey="paramCategory" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="734"/>
        </SelectParameters>
        <DeleteParameters>
            <WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{E855D4F1-5106-48FE-AC42-AE5992837C20}"/>
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{E855D4F1-5106-48FE-AC42-AE5992837C20}"/>
        </UpdateParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <WebPartPages:DataFormParameter Name="ListID" ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{E855D4F1-5106-48FE-AC42-AE5992837C20}"/>
        </InsertParameters>
    </SharePointWebControls:SPDataSource>
</DataSources>

<datafields>@Title,Title;@Department,Department;@Company,Company;@Birthday,Birthday;@Full_x0020_Name,Full Name;@Account,AD User name;@Group_x0020_Code,GroupCode;@Group,
                    Group;@EmployeeID,EmployeeID;@CompanyCode,CompanyCode;@Unit,Unit;@Duty,Duty;@TitleCode,TitleCode;@Picture0,Picture;@JobTitle1,Designation;@EMail,E-Mail;
                    @Gender,Gender;@Education,Education;@SSN_x002f_CNIC,SSN/CNIC;@MaritalStatus,Marital Status;@Manager,Manager;@CRLoginName,CRLoginName;@Photo,Photo;
                    @Active,Active;@DateOfJoining,DateOfJoining;@WorkAddress,Address;@Introduction,Introduction;@Qualification,Qualification;@Responsibilities,Responsibilities;
                    @TechnicalSkills,TechnicalSkills;@MachineID,MachineID;@FavoriteBooks,FavoriteBooks;@Hobbies,Hobbies;@NewUserE,NewUserEntryWorkFlow;@tpIsManager,Is Manager;
                    @ID,ID;@ContentType,Content Type;@Modified,Modified;@Created,Created;@Author,Created By;@Editor,Modified By;@_UIVersionString,Version;@Attachments,Attachments;
                    @File_x0020_Type,File Type;@FileLeafRef,Name (for use in forms);@FileDirRef,Path;@FSObjType,Item Type;@_HasCopyDestinations,Has Copy Destinations;
                    @_CopySource,Copy Source;@ContentTypeId,Content Type ID;@_ModerationStatus,Approval Status;@_UIVersion,UI Version;@Created_x0020_Date,Created;@FileRef,URL Path;
                    @ItemChildCount,Item Child Count;@FolderChildCount,Folder Child Count;</datafields>
```

Now at technical skills I have to put data of columns technical skills 1, technical skills 2 and technical skills 3 instead of column technical skills. How it should be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing it here change the select at xsl. For multiple columns add multiple variables in xal and add them in select.